# Как заменить текст в селект2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

когда ввожу в инпут и нет совпадений
то выдает

> no results found

как заменить на текст-

> ничего на найдено

использую https://select2.org/

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select an option',
  dropdownParent: ".list"
});
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.list .select2-container--open {
  position: static !important;
}
.list .select2-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}

body {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.btn.active {
  
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AL">пункт 1</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
<div class="list"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum blanditiis sapiente voluptas cumque architecto consequuntur ducimus reprehenderit modi non nihil repudiandae a, similique unde doloremque, voluptatem inventore praesentium! Voluptate, eligendi.</p>

<button class="btn">button</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Берём файл](https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/develop/dist/js/i18n) с нужным языком, изменяем, если нужно, фразы на желаемые и [подключаем в настройках](https://select2.org/i18n)

Comment: Второй вариант, который так же указан в документации - это изменить в объекте `language` возвращаемое значение. В вашем случае так: `language: { noResults: function() { return "ничего на найдено ...";  } }`. [Пример в песочнице](https://jsfiddle.net/k0gL5qnb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам необходимо скачать скрипт к себе на сервер вот этот скрипт `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js">`
Открыть его, поиском найти эту фразу и изменить ее. Далее прописать на странице путь к правленому скрипту.
Лицензия данного скрипта (см. [ссылку](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/LICENSE.md)) позволяет делать с ним все что угодно.